# Cosemi-simple FRT Hopf Algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

This question is a somewhere similar variation on an old [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223333/compact-quantum-groups-and-frt-algebras) of mine. Given an FRT-algebra, which is to say, roughly, that it can be constructed from an R-matrix in the Yang--Baxter sense (see Klimek and Schmudgen for more details), do there exist conditions for it to be cosemi-simple as a Hopf algebra